# Selenium after clicking Log in, username and password fields become blank

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to log in a web page using Selenium. Here are the code:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_UserName")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_UserName")).SendKeys("name");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_Password")).Clear();      
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_Password")).SendKeys("password");
```

After entering username and password, I tried four ways to log in:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_Password")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_Password")).Submit();
driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$MainContent$LoginCtrl$ctl05")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='Log in']")).Click();
```

After logging in, the page still stays in log in page. username and password fields become blank.

Please advise and thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like this and solved problem:

```
while (driver.FindElements(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_UserName")).Count > 0 || driver.FindElements(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_Password")).Count > 0) {
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_UserName")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_UserName")).SendKeys("username");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_Password")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_Password")).SendKeys("password");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$MainContent$LoginCtrl$ctl05")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
```

Comment: Not that it really matters if this is an isolated test environment, but you may want to remove credentials from this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,May be button takes time to appear :

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_UserName")).Clear();          
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_UserName")).SendKeys("name");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_Password")).Clear();      
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_Password")).SendKeys("password");     
Thread.Sleep(10000);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_Password")).Click();
```

OR

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_UserName")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_UserName")).SendKeys("name");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_Password")).Clear();      
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_Password")).SendKeys("password");     
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_LoginCtrl_Password")).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried both but still have that problem. Finally I solved this problem. I posted my answer below.